# I can't enable WSL on Windows 11 version 22H2

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I recently installed Windows 11 version 22H2 and I have a big problem: I can't install WSL.

When the update appeared in Windows Update, I started the installation process and after a while the computer stopped responding, so I forced shutdown. Once I turned it back on, it went into WinRE mode, so I restored the laptop to the state before the update, which allowed me to continue working.

I then tried a clean install of Windows 11 version 22H2. Once the OS and driver installation was complete, I tried installing WSL from the console using the `wsl --install` command, following all the instructions on the [Install Linux on Windows with WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install) page.

I have restored the system several times, but the result is always the same: every time I reboot the operating system to complete the WSL installation, the blue screen appears and enters WinRE mode, and I can only go back to a restore point prior to the WSL installation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced the same problem for my Lenovo X1 Extreme.

My problem solved when I configure these things in BIOS.

Enter BIOS > Security > Virtualization > Set this values:

Kernel DMA Protection = **Disabled**

Intel virtualization technology = **Enabled**

Intel VT-d feature = **Enabled**

Enhanced Windows Biometric Security = **Disabled**

Comment: Exactly this, but I only had to enable `Intel Virtualization Technology` on my computer.

Comment: I see, in my machine.. the Intel virtualization is enabled by default but still getting the error. Hahaha, so I don't know which options that cause the issue. But, generally this settings is for all. (maybe).